# Flash Player unable to proceed with the installation (versions 11 onwards)

Tags: macos, installation, version, flash

I have difficulties installing the latest version of Adobe Flash Player (14.0.0.125) on my Mac OS X 10.9.3 (Mavericks).  Every time I do so, it fails at 90% with the following error message.

```
Error: Unable to proceed with the installation
```

When I go to troubleshoot the problem, I find that I have version 13.0.0.214 of Flash Player installed on my system, and that the (alleged) latest version (for Mac OS X 10.6, 10.7 and 10.8) is 13.0.0.201 (see following URL).

http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/installation-problems-flash-player-rvm.html

Further research has revealed that *the* latest version of Flash Player (for Mac OS X 10.6, 10.7, 10.8 and 10.9) is 14.0.0.125 (see following URL).

http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/installation-problems-flash-player-mac.html#main-pars_heading_7

This is not the first time I have experienced problems upgrading Adobe Flash Player.  I experienced a similar problem before upgrading to Mac OS X 10.9 except with different version numbers of the same software. That is, the version that was installed was greater than the version that was downloaded.  Note that I did not experience this problem with prior versions of the OS (i.e. Mac OS X 10.6 and 10.7).

This time I went one step further and used a different default browser to locate, download and install (what I presumed was the latest version of) Flash Player.  No difference....

My question is, why does my default browser point to an older version of the installation software, and how can I resolve this?  Also, correct me if I am wrong but, the reason I have a 'later' version of the software (that is, version 13.0.0.214) is due to the OS upgrade?  I do not recall ever upgrading Adobe Flash Player....

Not sure whether or not this is relevant, but I also have Adobe Creative Suite 5 installed on my system (which was also successfully upgraded during all OS upgrades).

---

UPDATE: Did a bit more searching on the Adobe forums and found a link to a previous version of [Adobe Flash Player version 13.0.0.223](http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/get/flashplayer/current/licensing/mac/install_flash_player_13_osx.dmg). Although not the latest version, I have successfully installed it. That is, after I uninstalled the older version of Flash Player. The problem I experienced sounds almost identical to this [installation problem](https://forums.adobe.com/message/4807206).

I am still, however, experiencing the same problem when upgrading to version 14 of Flash Player (even through System Preferences). Seems to be a problem with the installer, and not my system configuration since, to resolve this problem, I uninstall Flash Player (like before) and successfully installed [Flash Player version 14 OS X](http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/get/flashplayer/current/licensing/mac/install_flash_player_14_osx.dmg), which I found and downloaded from the same web site.